# Возможно ли увеличить весь вывод в окно, sfml?

Tags: c++, sfml

ПИшу пиксельную игру: когда персонаж с картой находится в малом масштабе он идет точно по пикселям, но если использовать setScale то персонаж начинает останавливаться между пикселями:

[image: Персонаж остановился поверх двух пикселей рядом стоящих]

Решение для это по моему мнению только одно увеличить весь конечный вывод в окно, как это сделать?

Comment: Почитайте про шейдеры и sf::View